# Algorithms LaTeX \EndForAll and "Some Blocks are not closed!!!"

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm new to the `algorithm` package in LaTeX and need help figuring out how to debug my MWE below, which gives six errors.  It look complicated, but half the errors are the same thing and in one case I'm obviously not using `\EndForAll` correctly, even though it seems intuitive (and there's nothing online about it).  I'm particularly curious about the `\end{algorithmic}` error, which says that `Error: Some blocks are not closed!!!`  I provided `End` statements on every block I opened so I don't understand this error.

I would really appreciate any feedback.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}

\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{myalgo}{}
  \State $\textit{things} \gets \textit{stuff}$
  \State $g(thing)$ \gets \text{stuff }(\textit{material})$
  \Comment{comment}{}
  \ForAll{{$stuff$ in $things$}} :
  \State \text{Material }(\textit{stuff})
  \Comment{stuff}{}
  \State \text{\it{k}} = (\textit{stuff}, \textit{things})
  \EndForAll
  \If {$k$ is good}:
  \State $things$
  \EndIf
  \ForAll{{$things$ in $stuff$}} :
  \State $abs\bigg|{stuff} - {things}\bigg|$
  \State Material \bigg\{$abs \bigg|{stuff} - {things}\bigg|$\bigg\}
  \Comment{Ending}{}
  \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `\EndForAll`, but `\EndFor`. You're missing one.

You're also inconsistent in how you treat variables and function names. Here's an edited version with a couple of helper macros. Be careful when entering and exiting math mode.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{myalgo}{}
  \State $\var{things} \gets \var{stuff}$
  \State $g(\var{thing}) \gets \func{stuff}(\var{material})$
  \Comment{comment}{}
  \ForAll{$\var{stuff}$ in $\var{things}$}:
  \State $\func{Material}(\var{stuff})$
  \Comment{stuff}{}
  \State $k = (\var{stuff}, \var{things})$
  \EndFor
  \If {$k$ is good}:
  \State $\var{things}$
  \EndIf
  \ForAll{$\var{things}$ in $\var{stuff}$}:
  \State $\func{abs}\big|\var{stuff} - \var{things}\big|$
  \State $\func{Material} \bigl\{\func{abs} \big|\var{stuff} - \var{things}\big|\bigr\}$
  \Comment{Ending}{}
  \EndFor
  \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Note that `\bigg` is way too big!

[image]

Comment: Very helpful answer.  Is there a way to add a nice subscript in LaTeX... of all places I've seen, it's usually just `\_`, but I was wondering if you had other thoughts especially in an algorithm package like this, where it may look different?

Comment: @white_rabbit If you want to add a subscript to `k`, just type `k_{1}`. But your question is too generic, I'm afraid.

Comment: For example, white_rabbit I would type white\_rabbit.  But the underscore is kind of short looking in LaTeX.  I was wondering if I could actually make it look like a full-fledged underscore?

Comment: @white_rabbit `\var{white\_rabbit}` if it's a variable.

Comment: That's actually what I tried, too.  It looks kind of short, but maybe that's the best it can do.  Any other possibilities to attempt?

Comment: @white_rabbit See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34131/4427

Answer (score 2):

You had several syntactical mistakes:

1. In the second `\State`, you had a spurious `$` sign after `(thing)`.
2. The closing command is `\EndFor`, not `\EndForAll`.

The corrected code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}

\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{myalgo}{}
  \State $\textit{things} \gets \textit{stuff}$
  \State $g(thing) \gets \text{stuff }(\textit{material})$
  \Comment{comment}{}
  \ForAll{{$stuff$ in $things$}} :
  \State \text{Material }(\textit{stuff})
  \Comment{stuff}{}
  \State \text{\it{k}} = (\textit{stuff}, \textit{things})
  \EndFor
  \If {$k$ is good}:
  \State $things$
  \EndIf
  \ForAll{{$things$ in $stuff$}} :
  \State $abs\bigg|{stuff} - {things}\bigg|$
  \State Material \bigg\{$abs \bigg|{stuff} - {things}\bigg|$\bigg\}
  \EndFor
  \Comment{Ending}{}
  \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Use `texdoc algpseudocode` in a terminal to access the documentation for the `algorithmicx` bundle in your system.