# How to typeset linguistic AVS

Tags: tables, arrays, linguistics

How can I typeset attribute value structures (AVS) and rules like the ones seen here?

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Comment: Why not use the `avm` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a possibly handy syntax: the `avs` environment takes as optional argument the column specifier for the second column (default `l`); it should contain one or more `\avsline` commands; the optional argument is meant to specify a color.

Some auxiliary macros are defined for easing specification of symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,array,xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\avsplus}{}{$+$}
\NewDocumentCommand{\avsminus}{}{$-$}
\NewDocumentCommand{\avsto}{}{\unskip${}\to{}$\ignorespaces}

\newenvironment{avs}[1][l]
 {$\left\lbrack\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\scshape}l@{${}:{}$}#1@{}}}
 {\end{tabular}\right\rbrack$}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\avsline}{O{}mm}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { rafael/avs } { color=black,#1 }
  \color{\g_rafael_avs_linecolor_tl} #2 &
  \color{\g_rafael_avs_linecolor_tl} #3 \\
 }

\keys_define:nn { rafael/avs }
 {
  color .tl_gset:N = \g_rafael_avs_linecolor_tl,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{avs}
\avsline{place}{dental}
\avsline{manner}{fricative}
\avsline{voice}{\avsplus}
\end{avs}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{avs}[r]
\avsline[color=red]{consonantal}{\avsplus}
\avsline[color=red]{voice}{\avsplus}
\avsline{place}{\textit{bilabial}}
\avsline{manner}{\textit{stop}}
\end{avs}
\avsto
\begin{avs}[r]
\avsline[color=blue]{consonantal}{\avsplus}
\avsline[color=blue]{voice}{\avsminus}
\avsline{place}{\textit{bilabial}}
\avsline{manner}{\textit{stop}}
\end{avs}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for the work. How would you add the "/ _ #" part at the end? I tried adding `/\underline{\hspace{.3cm}}\#`, but it doesn't look right.

Comment: @RafaelBankosegger `/\_\#`

Comment: That's what I initially tried, but then the underscore appears too short, so I used the hspace workaround. What I want, I guess, is something similar to your `\avsto` command, so that I can type `\avsspace` or something instead of `\underline{\hspace{.3cm}}`. @egreg, if you could work that part into your answer, that would be great!

Comment: @RafaelBankosegger See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34129/narrow-underscore-in-listings-package

Comment: One thing that has always bothered me with the bracketed notion produced by `array` is that it produces visible white space when it glues parts of the brackets together. See [this zoom](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=62189822955591151915) for a clearer example. I can open a separate question about it, but is there an easy way to avoid these spaces?

Comment: @Sverre It's just a viewer issue.

Comment: @egreg True, but it appears in all pdf viewers I've used, and it doesn't appear for brackets not produced by `array`. So the issue is nevertheless caused by `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package amsmath and try this:

```
\begin{equation}
\left[ \begin{array}{lcl}
\mathrm{PLACE} &:& \mathrm{dental}\\
\mathrm{PLACE} &:& \mathrm{dental}\\
\mathrm{MANNER} &:& \mathrm{fricative}\\
\mathrm{VOICE} &:& +
\end{array}\right]
\qquad


\left[\begin{array}{lcl}
\mathrm{PLACE} &:&\mathrm{dental}\\
\mathrm{PLACE} &:&\mathrm{uvular}\\
\mathrm{VOICE} &: &+\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
```

Interchange mathrm to mathbf if you require bold!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{I}{!{:}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{tabular}{lIl}
PLACE & dental \\
PLACE & dental \\
MANNER & fricative \\
VOICE & + \\
\end{tabular}\right]
\quad
\left[\begin{tabular}{lIl}
PLACE & dental \\
PLACE & uvular \\
VOICE & + \\
\end{tabular}\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{tabular}{lIl}
CONSONANTAL & + \\
VOICE & + \\
\end{tabular}\right]
\rightarrow
\left[\begin{tabular}{lIl}
CONSONANTAL & dental \\
VOICE & - \\
\end{tabular}\right] / \_ \#
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]